# Laravel - How to insert multi-dimensional Array in DB

Tags: arrays, laravel, multidimensional-array, eloquent, laravel-9

I have the array as below;

[image]

I'd like to insert each `name` keys into `tableName` and get the inserted id.
For the `steps`, each of them will be inserted into another table `tableSteps` including the last inserted id of the `name`.

Like as below screenshot.

[image]

In my controller,

Here's what I've done so far.

```
    $instructionsArrays = $request->instructions;
    $max = count($instructionsArrays);

    for ($x = 1; $x <= $max; $x++) {
        foreach($instructionsArrays as $instructionsArray){
            Instruction::updateOrCreate(
                ['recipe_id' => session()->get('recipeArr.id'), 'sequence' => $x],
                ['name' => $instructionsArray['name']],
            );
        }
    }
```

I was able to save sequence numbers but for names it saves only the last `name` key.
And... I'm really lost..

Comment: why are u using update or create function? Im trying to solve this for you but the part Im missing is why are u using that

Comment: You ever think about that this happens because all your test values are `Some value` ?

Comment: @geertjanknapen I was gonna say that but Im still waiting for him to explain xd

Comment: Yeah the `updateOrCreate` does not really make sense, but it's not really the question being asked..

Comment: @Kneegrows, I'm using updateOrCreate if incase it doesn't exist for that particular Recipe_ID. I can use create or whatever but I have an issue with such.

Comment: @Borgy but you will need the record ID to reference it in the steps table.

Comment: @geertjanknapen, I'm sure `Some values` were not the reason because I've entered the correct values but still getting the same.

Comment: @Kneegrows, Yes. that is why I need it.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you want from 2 for loops

```
foreach($request->instructions as $key => $val){
$id = Instruction::insertGetId(
    ['recipe_id' => session()->get('recipeArr.id'), 'sequence' => $key + 1],
    ['name' => $val['name']],
);
$data = []; //bulk insertion
$created_at = now();
foreach($val["steps"] as $step){
    array_push($data, ["header_id" => $id, "name" => $step, "sequence" => $key+1, "created_at" => $created_at]); //why insert sequence when you can obtain it from the relationship?
  }
  Steps::insert($data);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. But getting this error. `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'name' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: But when I dd($val['name']), it shows the `name`. :'(

Comment: That happens if you don't have fillable attributes in your model.
protected $fillable = ['sequence', 'name', 'header_id'];

Comment: It has `name` in the Model. I played around and I was thinking there were 2 `name` columns in both tables. So what I did is rename it to `instructions_name` and the other is `steps_name` and yes, it worked. Anyway, your suggestion gave me an idea of how can I solve my problem. I will post the correct code next. I marked your answer as `very` useful :). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

With the help of the answer of @Kneegrows, I came up with the code below and it is now working. Thank you.

```
        foreach ($request->instructions as $key => $val) {
         $instruction = Instruction::updateOrCreate(
                ['recipe_id' => session()->get('recipeArr.id'), 'sequence' => $key + 1],
                ['instructions_name' => $val['name']],
            );
        $id = $instruction->id;
        $data = []; //bulk insertion
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($val["steps"] as $step) {
            if(!is_null($step)){
                array_push($data, ["instruction_id" => $id, "steps_name" => $step, "sequence" => $i]);
                $i++;
            }
        }
        Steps::insert($data);
    }
```